# Full screen Overlay issue

Tags: css

I'm trying to overlay screen when displaying a progress bar, but the overlay is not happening properly, couple of the DIV's are still highlighted as shown in image.

Im using following CSS style, please suggest what is causing the issue

```
style = {
 qoverlay: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '0',
      left: '0',
      background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
      'z-index': '50',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    }
}
```

Im using material-ui/core/Dialog

```
<Dialog open={this.state.confirmOpen} aria-labelledby='form-dialog-title' style={this.style.qoverlay}>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might need to increase the value of the `z-index`. Try changing it from `50` to `99999`. Or check the `z-index` value of the elements that remain visible and use a higher number for your overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Mark position is fixed this will resolve your problem. The absolute is positioned relative to its first parent marked as relative.

Comment: Still the same issue with,
qoverlay: {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '0',
      left: '0',
      background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
      zIndex: 50,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    }